# C stringification: convert constant to integer

Tags: c, macros, stringify, stringification

I need to convert defined constants to their integer values so I came up with this macro (STR_TO_CONST) for doing so...

```
#define STRFY_VAL(s) #s
#define STRFY_KEY(s) STRFY_VAL(s)
#define STR_TO_CONST(s) atoi(STRFY_KEY(s))
```

It works, but I'm wondering if there are any potential problems with it as I've never encountered this macro before despite having searched considerably for something like it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your problem.  Do you have an example of your use-case?

Answer (score 5):

The reason you never encountered this is that it's *utterly pointless*, but let's explain by example. Say you have the following:

```
#define FINALANSWER 42

// ...

int x = 2 * STR_TO_CONST(FINALANSWER);
```

now, this is semantically no different from:

```
int x = 2 * FINALANSWER;
```

That's because preprocessor macros are ultimately just textual replacement happening before you actually compile. Therefore, `FINALANSWER` is just as good as an integer constant as `42` is.

Your "solution" to a non-existing problem just adds overhead in that it adds a new string constant to your code and an unnecessary function call as well.

Comment: And makes it more difficult to read and maintain, because you have to figure out what the macro does first. Granted, the name of this one makes it pretty clear, but that's not always the case.

Comment: Oh and it needlessly makes an expression evaluated at runtime from a *compile-time constant* ... well, yes, just don't do this, I hope my explanation is good enough :)

Comment: And the macro can have unexpected side effects... The list is too long. Bottom line: Avoid macros unless you absolutely have to use them, and even then make absolutely certain you know what you're doing.

Comment: I'll sign that bottom line, at least for beginners. I'd add *Macros are great, if you know when they are* ;)

Comment: Notice how I did not solicit advice as to wether or not this was an appropriate solution to a broader problem. I was merely asking if there were any apparent technical issues with the code.

Comment: @user2418731 chux' answer has a lot of additional reasons for **not** doing this, still I think the first thing to mention is indeed that it's pointless.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there are any potential problems with it (?)

Yes. Using `atoi()` to initialize  a global results in something like "error: initializer element is not constant"

```
int x = STR_TO_CONST(123);  // error
int y = 123; // no error

int main(void) {
  return x + y;
}
```

---

Hide warnings.  Only 1 line generated a useful warning 
"warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]"

```
int main(void) {
  int a = STR_TO_CONST(123456789012345);  // no warning
  int b = 123456789012345;                 // warning
  return a + b;
}
```

---

Range issue.   With 32-bit `int`, the below will likely exceed `atoi()` range resulting in *undefined behavior* with no warning.

```
int main(void) {
  long long z = STR_TO_CONST(123456789012345);
  return !z;
}
```